# ¿Cómo ordeno teniendo en cuenta dos campos?

Tags: python, ordenamiento

Supongamos que tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
tabla = [['M' ,45, 'positiva', 7],
['F',22,'negativa',6],
['M',19 ,'negativa',9],
['F',24,'positiva',10],
['F',27,'negativa',9],
['M',30,'positiva',10]]
```

y quiero ordenarla por los valores en la ultima columna, entiendo que un método para lograr esto es usando

```
tabla.sort(key = lambda x:x[3], reverse=True)
```

con lo cual obtengo la siguiente tabla

```
tabla = [['F', 24, 'positiva', 10],
 ['M', 30, 'positiva', 10], 
['M', 19, 'negativa', 9],
['F', 27, 'negativa', 9], 
['M', 45, 'positiva', 7], 
['F', 22, 'negativa', 6]]
```

mi duda es si ahora quiero ordenar los elementos de la última columna que son iguales por los valores de la segunda columna de forma decreciente para poder obtener la siguiente tabla, ¿cómo lo haría?

```
tabla = ['M', 30, 'positiva', 10], 
[['F', 24, 'positiva', 10],
['F', 27, 'negativa', 9],
['M', 19, 'negativa', 9],
['M', 45, 'positiva', 7], 
['F', 22, 'negativa', 6]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar una tupla para definir todos los elementos a tener en cuenta a la hora de ordenar:

```
sorted(tabla, key = lambda x: (x[3], x[1]), reverse=True)
#                              \__/  \__/
#                              1.º    2.º criterio
#                              criterio
```

Con tus datos, devuelve:

```
[['M', 30, 'positiva', 10],
 ['F', 24, 'positiva', 10],
 ['F', 27, 'negativa', 9],
 ['M', 19, 'negativa', 9],
 ['M', 45, 'positiva', 7],
 ['F', 22, 'negativa', 6]]
```

Miremos un ejemplo más simple:

```
>>> tabla = [[1,2,3], [1,3,4], [2,1,3], [2,3,4]]

>>> sorted(tabla, key = lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))
[[1, 2, 3],
 [1, 3, 4],
 [2, 1, 3],
 [2, 3, 4]]
>>> sorted(tabla, key = lambda x: (x[0], -x[1]))
[[1, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3],
 [2, 3, 4],
 [2, 1, 3]]
```

Fíjate que puedes poner el valor en negativo para conseguir un `reverse=True`.